# What version of Kubernetes Dashboard (1.6 or 1.7) is this Yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

From [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-dashboard) documentation, there are separate processes for accessing dashboard depending on what version is installed, yet I cannot find any way to determine which version is installed.

This uses the following YAML:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard-head.yaml

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of development release, that is pushed after every successful build of master build, triggered by CI.

The *head* tag of image means it's the most recent development version, at the time Kubernetes pulled the image from kubernetesdashboarddev repository.

In other words this is the most recent version (high above 1.7.X), [not recommended](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Installation#development-release) to use in production, which was not officially released.

*the use of this image is recommended with *imagePullPolicy: Always*, which means every time your Dashboard Pod is recreated, Kubernetes will pull it's most recent version from container registry.